# Почему возникает ошибка при создании вьюхи?

Tags: mysql

Вот условный запрос:

```
create table test (value char);

insert into test values ('a'), ('b');

create view test_view as
set @id = 0;
select (@id := @id + 1) as id, value
from test;
```

Сам по себе он (select если запустить отдельно) отрабатывает без проблем, но внутри вьюхи возникает ошибка:

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'set @id = 0' at line 1

В чем проблема? mysql 5.7

Comment: Потому что set это отдельный запрос. А select это уже второй запрос. А в view должен быть строго один запрос и он должен быть именно select, никаких set

Comment: Обратите внимание, что во всем на что я давал ссылки в ваших предыдущих вопросах, где используются переменные, я их инициализирую в части from. И это именно потому, что бы запрос был один и им можно было пользоваться везде, включая view

Comment: Кстати, всё одно ни хрена не получится - в представлениях нельзя использовать параметры и пользовательские переменные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно перенести `set` внутрь самого селекта, например, вот так:

```
select (@id := @id + 1) as id, value
from test
join (select @id := 0) t
```

Запрос будет работать, но только не внутри вьюхи: в них параметры использовать **нельзя**.